# is it possible to run compiled iron python scripts on PCs without iron python installed?

Tags: python, ironpython, exe

I'm using the pyc tool to compile IronPython scripts to executables, but can they be run without IronPython installed? If so what do I have to include?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can run it on other PC's without installing IronPy or Visual Studi (ergo, off the bat).
Sometimes you'd might need the Windows runtime libraries that you compiled the application with, but other then that.. yes you can execute it on any other Windows PC equal to the one your compiled it on.
(example, compiling on win7 will most likely run on win7 off the bat but not on a XP without the runtime libraries used on the compiling machine)

Comment: sounds good, but do I need to include libaries for IronPython too? And if so would IronPython.ddl and IronPython.Modules.ddl be enough?

Comment: No, anything related ti IronPython and Python you can ignore.. they are compiled into the binary executable. Why don't you try it out? Compile it, copy to a USB stick and try it on another PC?

Comment: ok thanks, I'm at work right now and every pc here has ironPython installed. I'll try at home since I don't want to reinstall it later

Comment: Gl and hope it works.
If it doesn't work, give a comment and i'll give you the locations of the **runtime dll's** you'll need (i'm a Unix developer mainly so I don't have many windows machines during the day) :)

Answer (score 0):

I think with py2exe and the .net framework

Comment: This user has been going about it for almost two days now asking about IronPython because he uses Visual Studio 2010 (i think it was), that's the reason why he asks about IronPy, he's already looked at py2exe.. only reason i knnow this is because i've answered his other questions too :P

Comment: and you are really fast at doing so <3

Comment: Hehe, what's the fun in being last ;)